# php get file size from data uri

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have a form upload plugin in my form which upload the image using `data uri` such as

```
$img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZ...............
```

I need to have file size constraint such as file size should not exceed 1MB.

I can get the image dimension(width & height) using `list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);`.

How can I get the file size for the same. Is there any pre defined function in `php` which I can use to get the file size of `data uri`

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have that check at the client? (JS)

Comment: but at the client side too, I have data uri. So I am unable to get file size at client side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `strlen` to get the size of the string (and therefore, the file) in bytes. base64 data is ~1/3 larger than binary data, so don't forget to `base64_decode` first.

Then your code is:

```
$img = 'base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZ...............';
echo 'File Size: ' . strlen(base64_decode($img));
```

Don't forget to get rid of the headers ("data:image/jpeg", etc.) if you want to be more accurate.

Comment: @TechMech no problem. Select the answer so others know this works as well :)

Comment: Hi Tushar, Can i achieve the same using javascript or jquery?